# Should I use standalone service for angular custom APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular-2+, electron

I'm working on a Angular Electron application where we display loading screen while the application is starting up. This means we have to do couple of BE requests and only remove the loader when we receive desired answers. We only read data in those calls, there are no write calls there.

Everything works but the INITIALIZER keeps growing in complexity and gains more and more `deps` with every request from Product Owner. This it's current state:

```typescript
// app-init.ts
export function initApp(
  healthService: HealthService, // Spring health - retryWithBackOff to handle BE not running
  sseService: SseService, // Opens SSE channel
  clientService: ClientService, // Project specific
  resultService: ResultsService, // Project specific
  loggerService: LoggerService, // self explanatory
  messageService: MessageService // helps to propagate status messages to loader screen
): () => Promise<any> {
// ...
}

// app.module.ts
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initApp,
  multi: true,
  deps: [HealthService, SseService, ClientService, ResultsService, LoggerService, MessageService],
},
```

My questions is, wouldn't it be better to create one use only service, to execute initial requests within the `APP_INITIALIZER`?  I know this goes against the DRY principle but I see a benefit here. Plus all our services and models are generated from API, we just run an `npm` command to update them. This should keep the good pretty stable.

It would look like this:

```typescript
// app-init.ts
export function initApp(
  initService: InitService, // Would group Health + Project specific services
  sseService: SseService, // Opens SSE channel
  loggerService: LoggerService, // self explanatory
  messageService: MessageService // helps to propagate status messages to loader screen
): () => Promise<any> {
// ...
}

// app.module.ts
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: initApp,
  multi: true,
  deps: [InitService, SseService, LoggerService, MessageService],
},
```

If the need for a new Project Specific service call would arise, we would just add it to InitService. This would prevent INITIALIZER `deps` from growing although it would introduce duplicity of some calls.

Is it a good idea? Or is there a better way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal point of view:
All "Best Practices" like "Do not repeat yourself" (DRY), "Single Responsibility Principle" (SRP), "You aint gonna need it" (YAGNI) and all the others are quite important and should always be considered. But not always applied. :-)
Especially because some of them contradict each other in certain cases.

My approach based on my coding goals:
Humans loves to seperate information into chunks.
Humans can normally catch between 5 and 10 chunks in one glance (7 is a good value).
(by the way, thats the reason why long numbers, like the IBAN or the ISBN are splitted like "DE44 1234 5678 9123 45" because its much easier to work with than with "DE4412345678912345")
Because of that reason i try to have not to many code chunks together.
If i have less then 7 services which i need at the initialisation, it would be kind of okay for me to call them directly.

If it gets more i would start to group.

Beside that, from a pure reading perspective, do i need the information that the all those services are needed at startup? Does it give me any additional value, if i am not specificley interested in the startup behavior?
I think not.

Therefore it would be totally fine for me to create one "InitApplicationService" which then orchestrates a bunch of specific services.
Because as a reader, then i see "ahhh there is some stuff that is done at initialisation" but if i am not really interested in that, my eyes can directly move on to the relevant stuff.
If i am interested, i do the additional click and look inside that service.

The same logic i apply to other places. Like if statements.

```
if(cage size = L && cage.stability > 50 && cage.contains(water) && cage.contains(food)){ ... }
```

against

```
if( isCageForLions(cage) ) { ... }
```

Easier to read and if really want to know what is relevant for a lion cage, then i look into the method.

Long story short, i produce boilerplate code, which does not have any functional value. But it makes the code easier to read and easier to understand. Which is an important value by itself in my eyes.
Also in my experience, when i group things, i have to think hard for a good group name. And quite often that gives me a few more insight into the grouped elements as well.